# How to change value of file from a fish function when sudo is required?

Tags: shell, fish

I've tried to create the following:

```
function change_brightness
    set -l brightness_level $argv[1]
    if not string match -r '^[1-9][0-9]*$' $brightness_level
        echo "Expect a single non-zero integer value to be passed."
        return 1
    end
    sudo echo $brightness_level > /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness
end
```

When I run this function I get the following output:

```
$ change_brightness 30
30
warning: An error occurred while redirecting file '/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness'
open: Permission denied
```

I'm not sure why the permission is denied, but I'm not sure why `30` is being echo'd to the console either (i was just expecting this to be written to the setting file).

## Edit - running from shell with sudo

The following doesn't work:

```
$ sudo change_brightness 30
[sudo] password for user: 
sudo: change_brightness: command not found
```

## Solution

```
function change_brightness
    set -l brightness_level $argv[1]
    if not string match -r '^[1-9][0-9]*$' $brightness_level
        echo "Expect a single non-zero integer value to be passed."
        return 1
    end
    echo $brightness_level | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness
end
```

Comment: try `$ sudo change_brightness 30`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone doesn't work - added output to post

Comment: Same problem as in other shells (the redirection is performed by the *shell* which runs as your normal user) and same solution: Do `echo string | sudo tee /path/to/file`.